# how to get url of specific version document sharepoint C#

Tags: sharepoint-server

i want to get the download link of some previous version of a document.

i know different number is represent different version.

```
/_vti_history/1 -> version 0.1
/_vti_history/2 -> version 0.2
.....
/_vti_history/? -> version 1.0
```

how to get this url in C# with the version number?

Comment: For major versions, you need to multiply by 512. Eg> 1.0 -> /_vti_history/512, 2.0 -> /_vti_history/1024

Answer (score 2):

You can use Versions Web Service for this  (_vti_bin/versions.asmx?op=GetVersions) or use below:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPFolder folder = web.Folders["Shared Documents"];
SPFile file = folder.Files["abc.doc"];
SPListItem item = file.Item;

foreach (SPListItemVersion v in item.Versions)
{
        //Versioned File Data
        byte [] dBytes = v.OpenBinary();
        int version=(int)v["_UIVersion"]
        {
            string Url=web.Url.TrimEnd('/') + "/_vti_history/" + version + "/" + file.Url;
        }
}
```

Comment: is there any formula? for example: 0.1 = 0 +1, 0.2 = 0+2.........1.0 = x, 1.1  = x+1, 1.2 = x+2.....2.0 = y, 2.1 = y+1